# Entropy of sum is sum of entropies

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Having $X$ and $Y$ discrete random variables above finite set. Z is defined as $Z=X+Y$ when does the following happen:

$$H(Z)=H(X)+H(Y)$$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is not true in general.

$$H(X,Z)=H(Z)+H(X \mid Z) = H(X)+H(Z \mid X) $$

But $H(Z \mid X)=H(X+Y \mid X)=H(Y \mid X)$.

Further, if we assume $X,Y$ are **independent**, then $H(Y \mid X)=H(Y)$ and

$$ H(Z)=H(X)+H(Y)-H(X \mid Z)$$

We still need $H(X \mid Z)=0$ (knowing the sum lets me know the summands). This is only true in the very special case in which $x_1+y_1 \ne x_2+y_2$ for any set of values with positive probability.
If both $X$ and $Y$ comes from the same set, then it's only true in the trivial case of a single element support.

Comment: Why $H(X+Y|X) = H(Y)$ I know that  $H(X+Y|X) = H(Y|X)$ but why is that equal to $H(Y)$

Comment: @HannaKhalil You are right, I was assuming independence, but that was not stated in the problem. I added a clarification.

Comment: @leonbloy is it ok to say that $H(Z)>H(X)$ and similarly $H(Z)>H(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent? And can this result be generalized to any number of independent random variables?

Comment: @FrankMoses That's rather obvious(at least with the non strict inequality). From the last eq, $H(Z)=H(Y) +I(X;Z) \ge H(Y)$

Comment: @HannaKhalil Could you please explain why H(X+Y|X)=H(Y|X) ?

Comment: @Niousha that's because given $X$, the randomness in $X + Y$ is only coming from $Y$ so $H(X + Y | X) = H(Y | X)$.

Answer (score -3):

I am afraid H(Z|X)  is not equal to H(Y|X), if X and Y are independent and Z = X+Y, because say X and Y are binary and independent, then X and Y say nothing about each other, but Z = 0 => X = 0, and Z = 2 => X = 1. So H(X|Z) is not equal to H(X|Y)=H(Y).

Comment: This answer does not address the question.